# Bad Request.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,StorageExtendedMessage=Block blobs are not supported

Tags: .net, azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create an azure data factory by following this article [Create, monitor, and manage Azure data factories using Data Factory .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-create-data-factories-programmatically)

Now I am getting following error:

> Copy activity encountered a user error at Sink side: ErrorCode=UserErrorBlobUploadFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when trying to upload blob 'https://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/adftutorial/apifactoryoutput/20140809-00/Data.27643436-2075-4d2f-9ae4-4b8626cc1b69.txt', detailed message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,StorageExtendedMessage=Block blobs are not supported.
>   RequestId:
>   Time:2017-01-09T20:29:53.5808585Z,,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Transfer client has encountered a fatal error when performing the data transfer.,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,StorageExtendedMessage=Block blobs are not supported.
>   RequestId:
>   Time:2017-01-09T20:29:53.5808585Z,,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,'.

[image]

Can someone point me where I am making mistake?

Note: The blob type is "PageBlob" defined in my azure storage.

Comment: Is your storage account's redundancy type `Premium LRS`?

Comment: Yes, It is Premium Locally-redundant storage (LRS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your account is `Premium LRS`, the behavior is correct as such kind of storage accounts only support `Page Blobs`.

If your intention is to use a storage account with `Block Blobs`, you must create a new storage account where the redundancy type is not `Premium LRS`.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I created a new storage account with Standard Read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS) and it worked.